# Dangling modifiers in sentences involving "Looking back"

Tags: participles, dangling-participles

Is there a dangling modifier in each of the following sentences?

1. "Looking back, not learning cycling at an early age is my biggest regret."
2. "Looking back, my biggest regret is not learning cycling at an early age."

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say _not learning to ride a bicycle. Cycling_ is the activity rather than the skill.

Comment: 'Looking back' has probably attained idiom status as a standalone sentence modifier. 'In hindsight'; no 'looker' needing to be directly referenced. Of course, the literal usage _is_ referential: 'Looking back, he saw the cyclist racing down the hill' where 'Looking back, the cyclist racing down the hill was what he saw' is awkward.

Answer (score 1):

They do have the appearance of a 'dangling modifier', but are probably acceptable.

The participial's subject is usually understood to be that of the main clause.

> Looking back, I think I treated them badly.

Here the subject of the main clause is also that of the participial *looking back*.

However, the subjects of the main clauses in the example sentences given - *not learning cycling at an early age* in the first sentence, and *my biggest regret* in the second - would be impossible to interpret as the subject of *looking back*. So even though these may be classified as 'dangling modifiers', there would be no ambiguity or confusion in the interpretation.

Another example of a participial that might be classified as a 'dangling modifier', but seems acceptable:

> Looking back, three relatively recent events signaled the depth of the
> problems that have overwhelmed the company. (GM AND ME, ALEX TAYLOR III, Fortune, Vol. 158, Iss. 11; pg. 92)